# javascript being sent everytime ajax requests rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that gets requested cross domain (I use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to accomplish this cross domain request without jsonp) through this ajax:  It responds with html

```
  //to ensure cache=true gets passed
  $.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) {
  options.cache = true;
  });

   //ajax requests html
   $.ajax({
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', api_key);
  },
  dataType: 'html',
  type: 'GET',
  url: url+'/gwsearch/ajax_search?d1='+d1_val+'&d2='+d2_val,
  crossDomain: true,
  success:function(result){

    $("#display").html(result);
  },
  error: function(result) {
    $('#display').html('Unauthorized client.');
  }
```

It responds with HTML that is displayed in `#display`. It has this script tag included in the html

```
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have input buttons on the newly displayed rails app, they look like this:

```
   <%= form_tag plans_collapse_plans_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:plangroup_id, plangroup.id) %>
      <%= image_submit_tag "collapse.png" %>
   <% end %>
```

Clicking on the input button does a POST.  The problem is that the input button will POST as many times as I've requested the cross domain rails app.  If I've requested the app 5 times, when I click an input button on the app, it will POST 5 times.

No matter how many times I send the initial ajax request, I still only have one application.js present; it is not physically cached more than one time.

EDIT:This is what my cache looks like, as you can see, only one application.js:
[image: cache]

The collapse_tplans POSTs all correspond to the same application.js file, same line.  If i had loaded the initial ajax request 6 times, I would have 6 collapse_tplan POSTs from application.js

[image: imagee]

My guess is that the script tag in the html page being sent is initializing a new version of jquery (since jquery is contained within application.js) and also, possibly duplicates of other things that are being loaded in application.js each time it is sent through the script tag.   With that said, under Network in Chrome, I can only see application.js being requested once, no matter how many times I execute the ajax request.

Any ideas? I need my input button to only POST once, like it should be doing. I'm truly stumped with this one.

Comment: `I still only have one application.js present` - what do you mean by this? I'm confused as to what your problem is?

Comment: @RichPeck I updated the question with a picture of my cache.  I mean that although I only have one application.js in cache, everytime I get the HTML response from the initial ajax request, it includes a script tag to the same application.js. The problem is that everytime I submit the input on the HTML response, it POSTs as many times as that script tag was loaded.  Ie, if I loaded  the HTML response 3 times, I will have 3 POSTs from my inputs.  These should only be posting once.  They all point to the same intiator: application.js

Comment: @RichPeck I'm saying that even though application.js is cached once, it seems to be reinitializing itself everytime the HTML page is loaded, creating new handlers for the input event.  That's my guess.

Comment: Whether an external script inserted into the document via a `<script>` element is _executed_ or not has nothing to do with whether that external resource is _cached_ already or not – obviously. (Or would you in the same manner expect an `<img>` not to show up if the image was chached already? No, of course not …)

Comment: very true, and it is indeed being cached, but I have another instance that highlights that something weird with jquery loading multiple times going on here.  1. application.js includes jquery. 2. I have jquery loaded on the parent page. 3. I load up fancybox and can close using a link that points to $.fancybox.close.  4. When I load the rails app, $.fancybox.close does not execute and I get method undefined errors in console @CBroe

Comment: this example highlights that at least one more copy of jquery is being loaded when the <script> tag is executed (the first time) and these problems that I'm describing in my original question above (POSTs being executed exactly as many times as I've run the ajax request) point to something being loaded multiple times.  And as I've shown the pic of my cache above, there is only one .js in my cache.  I don't know where to go from there.  @CBroe

Comment: I still don’t see why you think this has something to do with what your cache shows. You have a script element in the HTML code you load via AJAX, and jQuery puts that into the document so that it gets executed. I don’t know why you think the cache should prevent that from happening.

Comment: I have no idea what it has to deal with, I'm making no assumptions.  I'm simply putting down all of the information and coincidences I've found thus far so that someone more knowledgable than me can draw a conclusion @CBroe

Comment: What I do know is that my POSTs from the rails app should execute once, not n times, where n is the amount of times the ajax request was run.  @CBroe

Comment: @CBroe are you saying that you think this problem is because it's loading the js each time with the <script> tag?

Comment: Yes. // Docs for jQuery.ajax state that with `dataType:html` script elements included in the response are evaluated when inserted into the DOM. You could try to use `dataType:text` instead and see if that changes the behavior. Otherwise, you might have to filter out those script elements yourself; or see to it that your script does not attach the same events multiple times.

Comment: Now this is a prime example of why delegation is good practice... If you could add the code that binds the event handlers, I could tell you how and when to (un)bind what events

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the event handler code is generated by rails, using the following: `<%= form_tag plans_collapse_plans_path, :method => 'post', :remote => true do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:plangroup_id, plangroup.id) %>
      <%= image_submit_tag "collapse.png" %>
   <% end %>`

I have no other code I've done, this is what creates the event.  I'm not sure if it gets added to application.js or somewhere else, do you know? I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to stop my application from serving `application.js` and host it on the client.  I did this by the following:

app/views/layout/application.html.erb

I commented out the portion that serves `application.js`

```
<!--#  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> -->
```

In my client, I added

```
<script src="https://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/application.js"></script>
```

So the client serves `application.js`, and the rails html response gets sent without `application.js`.  Hope this makes sense to everyone, this took me a while to piece together!

Answer (score 4):

As [@natedavisolds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502777/86072) said, I guess your `application.js` script is executed 5 times, and the `click` hanlder of your `button` or the `submit` handler of your `form` is attached 5 times.

The fact that `application.js` is requested only once does not tell you how many times it is *executed*.

Try adding the following line at the beginning of the `application.js` script :

```
console.log('application.js executed');
```

and check your browser console to see how many times the message appears.

---

From your script's name, `application.js`, I guess it is meant to initalize the whole page, while your ajax request looks like it is only filling the `#display` node with search results.

You will have to refactor your application.js file :

- Read the code in your `application.js` file, and split the code in two parts : the part that concerns setting up the `#display` div, and the remainder.
- Move the first part in a separate `results.js` (or whatever name you see fit).
- Remove the `<script src="application.js">` node from the response to the `/gwsearch/ajax_search` request, and replace it with a `<script src="results.js">` node instead

Comment: added the `console.log` statement, it is executed every time I run the ajax as you had guessed.

Comment: how could I construct a form.js file and separately serve it?  1. Everytime the html page is loaded it would be loaded and processed again, giving me the same issue, no? 2. We tried building our own form code but it did not let us bypass CORS (our rack-cors gem is letting us do that, and has code it puts into application.js). Is there a way of building and serving a `form.js` whilst still having rails handle my form?  If not, what's the best way to handle this from here?

Comment: actually, is there a way to check, before `application.js` is loaded, if it has been loaded before?  I tried your way, but because of the new `application.js` loading, i can never find the variable i set.  Is there any other kind of identifier I could use to determine whether it's been loaded before?  Also, how would I put this before all of my code in application.js?  It says everything will be put underneath the manifest.

Comment: in fewer words, I want to find some sort of inherent flag that tells me if `application.js` was run before, and where I can put this to prevent my `application.js` from running if `flag == true`

Comment: thanks for the edit, could you tell me how I can remove `application.js` from my html page?  This gets served automatically with every HTML file with rails.  How can I disable this?  This way I can link my parent page (the client) to the script, so that it only gets called once.

Comment: This has helped me the most thus far.  I think the solution is to serve the file separately.  But, how can I tell rails not to package my html with `<script>application.js</script` ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using remote:true on the form, my theory is that rails.js is attaching a delegated event on the document element each time the script is loaded. 5 loads = 5 events = 5 ajax calls.

To fix it you could:

1. Remove the remote true and roll your own making sure it only happens once.
2. Remove the delegated events on document before loading a new script.

Try: (I am guessing here)

```
success:function(result){
  $(document).undelegate('submit.rails');
  $("#display").html(result);
},
```

Explanation:

Every time rails.js runs, a submit.rails event is added to the stack of events on document.  When you insert your html into the page, the rails.js code runs.  So, we undelegate the events first, then load the event back in.

Comment: 1. we're using rack-cors to bypass CORS and allow us to do stuff without jsonp, cross domain.  We've tried rolling our own but it won't work due to same-origin policy.  I don't know how the rack-cors gem works, but I know its code is hit when we do `:remote => true` 

2. Could you explain how this would be achieved?

Comment: also, what about jquery being reinitialized each time? Is that an actual issue or is that not possible?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree I don't think that jquery is an issue but rails.js is because it would define the event again.

Comment: this is working so far, for the most part.  A few of the first times I tried it I got 'no template found' error after the second time running the call.

Comment: could you explain why this works? I don't understand why if i'm undelegating `submit.rails` each time, the form even still submits.  I don't have any type of initialization flag, how is it even working?

Comment: you are undelegating the event from a previous page... but the running rails.js again.. which then re-adds the event. Confusing!  

Every time rails.js runs, a submit.rails event is added to the stack of events on document.  When you insert your html into the page, the rails.js code runs.  So, we undelegate the events first, then load the event back in. 

Not sure that makes any better sense. Does that help?

Comment: thanks for the solid explanation.  Really appreciate it.  I think the cleanest way to do this would be to serve the file separately, do you know if this rails.js code that's running is stored in application.js?  For example, we undelegated submit.rails, is this stored within application.js (in production)?  This way, if I store application.js separately and serve it once, could I get past this issue without undelegating events?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree disappointed that the bounty was given to someone else when I solved the problem. :( He really solved a different issue.

Comment: Your answer worked but eventually started failing for me, and it was not the process I wanted to take.  His answer helped me the most, but is still not the answer.  The answer (for me) is to host the `application.js` on the host client, and serve the html without `application.js`.  This way it will be loaded only once with the client.  @LeGEC caused me to think of this, so I awarded him the bounty, but I did not award him answer.  I will post the answer on here once I have tested it.  No hard feelings!